# regexp and txt file

Tags: python, regex

I have txt file and regexp and seems regexp working but i have excess symbols in tail

```
reg = re.findall(r"Source RPM: [ \t\n\r]*(.*?) \s", stdout, re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE|re.IGNORECASE)
```

and in output i have

```
liblqr-0.4.1-5.src.rpm
Size
gwenhywfar-4.1.0-2.src.rpm
Size
texlive-20110705-1.src.rpm
Size
mandriva-theme-1.4.9-9.2.src.rpm
Size
```

or

```
['liblqr-0.4.1-5.src.rpm\nSize']
['gwenhywfar-4.1.0-2.src.rpm\nSize']
['texlive-20110705-1.src.rpm\nSize']
['mandriva-theme-1.4.9-9.2.src.rpm\nSize']
```

What it is "nSize"?

Comment: It isn't nSize, it's \nSize. \n denotes a newline character.

Comment: (r"Source RPM: [ \t\n\r]*(.*?)\s" fix

Answer (score 2):

You're doing an ungreedy search for . ('any character'), including new lines, until a space is met. A new line isn't explicitly a space (' ') character, which is why removing it from your regex will make it work.

```
r"Source RPM: [ \t\n\r]*(.*?)\s"
                             ^ removed ' '
```